# Odbc open connection timeout

Tags: connection, timeout, odbc

I'm having an issue with Odbc connection.Open() , everything was working fine with the code below until it started to freeze in high latency - bad connections.

I'm using TMnetsim as a tool to simulate poor network connectivity. The code works fine in high latency situations but it just freezes if there is any packet loss. Even 1 single packet is enough to break the program. (It starts loosing packets after %3 Loss rate)

My question is, why doesn't connection.Open() not timeout and terminate? Event I explicitly set ConnectionTimeout to 5, it never timeout and stays there forever.

```
//connectionString: "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};SERVER=127.0.0.1;UID=master;PWD=pass;DATABASE=global;PORT=5432;"

using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        connection.ConnectionTimeout = 5;
        connection.Open(); // It hangs here forever... ? why?
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("...");
     }

     // code continues...
}
```

Well, I'm quite new to DB programming, your answers or suggestions are really worth a lot to me, thank you.

**Edit:**
connectionString: "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};SERVER=127.0.0.1;UID=master;PWD=pass;DATABASE=global;PORT=5432;" 
Database is Postgresql 8.x

Comment: Can you post your connetion string as well please? Where are you calling this code from? Are you calling it from a windows application?

Comment: Yes, its a C# - Wpf application. I included connection string in the code. It was working fine for local network or networks not far away. We started to get problems between long distance servers. I don't have chance to debug real scenario, so I'm using some tools to simulate poor network. The debugger shows, execution freezes at Open() method.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in the Odbc driver you are using. Are updated Odbc drivers for Postgres available for .Net, say from http://pgfoundry.org/projects/npgsql/? It could also be security related, are you sure the database server is reachable on that port with that username and password?

Comment: I assume drivers are OK, it should be. No problem with username, password and port. Now I'm suspecting this TMnetsim is not working as it should be. Will try with another tool...